# Unable to map Ctrl+Right or Ctrl+Left keybindings in Visual Studio Code

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

For some reason the "ctrl+right" / "ctrl+left" keybindings does not work for me in visual studio code. I took a screenshot of my keybindings.json and the Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting:

[image: Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting output]

I've tried the same mapping without the "when" condition or different value but it didn't seem to do anything.

If I change the keybinding to other keybinding like "ctrl+shift+right" or "cmd+right" then keybinding activates. The output here suggests that the keybinding is not found by VS code.

Is there something special about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> key combo?

I am using macOS Big Sur. I didn't touch any default system keybinding. I googled around for mac OS system keybinding but nothing came up under the "ctrl+right"/"ctrl+left" combo.

Before I switch over to VS code I was using Webstorm, which had this keybinding for many years. I never had any problem with it.

I'd appreciate any help or info.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Right</kbd> maps to desktop switching in macOS by default. So you need to go to Keyboard > Shortcuts in the *System Preferences* and remove <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Right</kbd> from Mission control

[image: Mission Control shortcuts]

See

- [Use Mission Control on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204100)
- [How can I make ctrl+right/left arrow stop changing Desktops in Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/18043)

Comment: Thank you! Very much appriciated it.